# Can't get factorial function to work

Tags: ruby, factorial

Factorial 1 and 2 works but 3 and 4 do not. I've worked the steps out on paper and do not see why they do not work. Any help is much appreciated.

```
def factorial(n)
  x = 1
  y = n

  while x < n
    n = n * (y-x)
    x = x + 1
  end
  return n
end

puts("factorial(1) == 1: #{factorial(1) == 1}")
puts("factorial(2) == 2: #{factorial(2) == 2}")
puts("factorial(3) == 6: #{factorial(3) == 6}")
puts("factorial(4) == 24: #{factorial(4) == 24}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that after each loop the value of `n` gets bigger and the condition `x < n` keeps executing until it hits a point where `n` becomes zero. If you pass 3 to the function on the third loop you will have:

```
while x(3) < n(6)
  n(6) = n(6) * (y(3) - x(3))
end
```

therefore `n` becomes 0 causing the loop to exit on the next round and the return value is obviously 0. To fix it you just need to replace `n` with `y` in the `while` condition:

```
while x < y
```

As a side note just another interesting way you could solve the factorial problem using recursion is:

```
def factorial(n)
  n <= 1 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1)
end
```

Comment: Recursion is really inefficient here. Plus, `factorial(9000)
SystemStackError: stack level too deep`, though you may not need factorials that are quite that large.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   def factorial(n)
      if n < 0
        return nil
      end

      x = 1
      while n > 0
        x = x * n

        n -= 1
      end

      return x
    end
```

Comment: Yeah that was the solution I was given but I wanted to try and make my code work even though yours is shorter. Thanks so much for the help.